# Smoothing a pair of arrays

Tags: code-golf, array

## Input

Two lists with binary values `(list_a, list_b)` of equal length=>3.

## Output

Two lists with binary values `(smoothed_a, smoothed_b)` with minimal Forward Difference while keeping the same sum before and after processing `sum(list_a) + sum(list_b) == sum(smoothed_a) + sum(smoothed_b)`.

**Forward Difference** being the absolute difference between items. For example:

- `[0, 1, 0]` would be `sum(abs([1, -1])) => 2`
- `[1, 1, 1]` would be `sum(abs([0, 0])) => 0`

## Illustrative test cases

Formatted as `(list_a, list_b) => (smoothed_a, smoothed_b)`

```
([0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 1])
=>
([0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

The sum of both arrays pairs is 5. The forward difference was minimized to 0.

```
([1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
=>
([0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

The sum of both arrays pairs is 4. The forward difference was minimized to 1.

## Test cases

Formatted as `(list_a, list_b): forward_diff => (smoothed_a, smoothed_b): min_diff` where `(smoothed_a, smoothed_b)` are potential solutions.

```
([0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0]): 3
([0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1]): 1

([1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0]): 0
([1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0]): 0

([0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1]): 4
([0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1]): 0

([1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]): 0
([1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]): 0

([1, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1]): 3
([1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]): 0

([1, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1]): 2
([1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]): 1

([1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0]): 3
([1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0]): 1
```

Comment: So, if I understand right, "forward difference" means \$\sum_{i} | x_i - x_{i+1} |\$?

Comment: @Rogem that is correct

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
FṢṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/t4c5FD3c2/v//XyPaQEcBiAzBpEGsjkK0IYwHYsRqAgA)

Explanation:

- **F**latten the list
- **Ṣ**ort the flattened list
- **ṁ**old the sorted flatten list in the shape of the input.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 4 bytes

```
O`\d
```

My shortest Retina answer thus far.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3z8hJuX//@hoQx0DHTCO1Yk20DGA8GJjAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8N8/ISbl///oaAMdAx1DIDaI1Yk2BLOAZGwsV3S0IVTGECgDUgXmgWUM4KIwEUOwLqg6qBpDqJkGcPNQVMF1GqCIIuw2wCIKc48himug6mJjAQ).

**Explanation:**

Sorts all digits in the input, and leaves every other character unchanged (including their positions).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 51 bytes

```python
def f(a,b):s=sorted(a+b);l=len(a);print s[:l],s[l:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcaxCoAgFEDRva9wfI8cqlHxS8RBUUkQFbWhr385BJfDbe@8a7mIfIgsguUOxVCj9hk82N2hzCqHAhZl66lMNrTIhg@dhaEIqbRnAnL2D5I@OVsdS7Pp/5bmAw)

Function that prints to STDOUT.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
½OΣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9Be/3OL////Hx1toGOgYwjEBrE60YZgFpCMjQUA)

```
½OΣ – Full program. Takes a list of two lists from the first CLA, outputs to STDOUT.
  Σ – Flatten (i.e. concatenate the contents of the 2 lists together).
 O  – Sort.
½   – Divide list in two halves (i.e. partition it into two equal-length sublists).
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 7 bytes

```
$$/:~@,
```

### explanation

```
$            NB. use the input shape
  $          NB. to shape the result of...
    /:~      NB. sorting the input
        @,   NB. after flattening it
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/VVT0reocdP5rcqUmZ@QraBgogKAOSImhgqGmgq6VQhpYyBAmaMAFAv8B)

Answer (score 0):

## C gcc compile flag 64bit, 31 bytes by Rogem

```
-Df(a,n)=qsort(a,n+n,4,"\x8b\x07+\x06\xc3")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDdCoJAEEbvfYpBKBTX8LcC8a63UC92txShtlpXEKJXb9utdG6bgeHw8XEuhocd51rrQcmRK3g4YKYXCmiVNwSYuYXzBHUaVOHY/EJ74fm/oo03tIoaKGdOFmZVbDkuPtXWW9uUQO5/g5s0uhY8d3WctxYuQeeCMWKCmCJmzT9Ohk6GToZOhk6GTnlSoxQQmTfoF2/PtBt0eGg9SoRf3oerVBYDQTLi1tOe1VO0C8zZ1hNPXf8N)

## C gcc 32bit, 37 bytes

```
f(a,n){qsort(a,n+n,4,"YXZ\x8B\x00+\x02QQQ\xC3");}
struct {
    int a[5], b[5];
} test;
int main() {
    test.a[0] = test.a[2] = test.b[1] = 1;
    f(&test, 5);
    printf ("%d%d%d%d%d\n", test.a[0], test.a[1], test.a[2], test.a[3], test.a[4]);
    printf ("%d%d%d%d%d\n", test.b[0], test.b[1], test.b[2], test.b[3], test.b[4]);
    return 0;
}
```

Written non-ASCII to `\x??` so se won't eat

Comment: Should probably mention that the input should be provided as a pointer to the first element of the list of lists.

Comment: @Rogem x86 and x64 use different calling method, so they can't have same asm  code

Comment: unfortunately, I do not have a 32-bit x86 to test it with, but the instructions `8b` (MOV), `2b` (SUB), `c3` (RET) are shared between the two. [This google hit](https://wiki.cdot.senecacollege.ca/wiki/X86_64_Register_and_Instruction_Quick_Start) seems to suggest that the registers would also be shared (in this case: `eax`, `rdi`, `rsi`)

Comment: @Rogem No. x86 use cdecl that push everything via stack

Comment: Alright, won't argue since I don't know.

Comment: Suggest adding `-zexecstack` to both versions, replacing `\x0n` with `\n` and adding `-m32` to the compiler argument of the i386 version.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
˜{2ä
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//9Jxqo8NL/v@PjjbQMdAxBGKDWJ1oQzALSMbGAgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/03OqjQ4v@a/zPzo62kDHQMcQiA1idaINwSwgGRuroxAdbQiVMgRKgZSBeRApA7gwXMgQrBGqEqbKEGquAcJMFHUIzQYowkguMMAmDHOWIcxRsQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
˜       # Flatten the (implicit) input list of lists
 {      # Sort it
  2ä    # Split it into two equal-sized lists (and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
⪪⭆⊗Ｌθ‹ι№⁺θη¹Ｌθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4ICcTSJYAOem@iQUaLvmlSTmpKRo@qXnpJRkahZo6Cj6pxcUamToKzvmlQA0BOaXFGoU6ChlAGUNNIAApgKrV1LT@/z862lBHwQCMDGN1uBSiDRDc2P@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Charcoal doesn't have a sort atom, but all we need to do is to put all the `1`s at the front of the list, which is done by counting them and then setting that many list entries to `1` and the remaining ones to `0`:

```
    θ           First input
   Ｌ            Length
  ⊗             Doubled
 ⭆              Map over implicit range and join
         θ      First input
          η     Second input
        ⁺       Concatenate
           ¹    Literal 1
       №        Count matches
      ι         Current index
     ‹          Less than
             θ  First input
            Ｌ   Length
⪪               Split into strings of that length
                Implcitly print each string on its own line
```

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 57 bytes

```r
function(a,b,s=1:sum(a|1),x=sort(c(a,b)))list(x[s],x[-s])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYkxCsAgDAC/0jGBCGYt9SXiYAVBaBWMgkP/bm2HOw6uzrgdasaeQ0slg6eTxPAu/Qb/MNIwUmqD8B1EvJI0GFYcDavE4YxradLEC40UgP9cRpwv)

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 60 bytes

```
def^(a:List[Int],b:List[Int])=(a:::b).sorted.splitAt(a.size)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcopCvkFpRkpqXUqzgWFCgUP0/JTUtTiPRyiezuCTaM68kVicJwda0BcpYWSVp6hXnF5WkpugVF@RkljiWaCTqFWdWpWr@LyjKzCvJydOI0wDp0TDUUTDQUYCSmjpgMQMwDyqsqanJVfsfAA)